# New comer, lost in translation from University PC to home PC in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

I will try to be as specific as posible. First of all, it's a really basic question, and you have to consider I have almost no knowledge in programing or the use of it. But I still have to learn it, and I would like to learn it.
I'm doing an optative in my university, it's programing, and they start with visual basic.
The proglem is the following, we have done a small program in Visual Basic in class. Now I'm trying to do it in my computer. I downloaded Visual Basic 2015, and tried doing the same, or similar things.
The problem is, that when I did this in the university, other values would appear. For example, when I added a button and went to the code, "Public Class Form1" would appear, followed by "Private Sub Form1_Load(..etc)".
Now what appears is "using System;" and a list of items. And then,

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication4
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
```

Is it a version thing, or are there steps the profesor didn't mention that I'm not aware of. If I replace the code, it appears as invalid. I tried looking and videos, but it appears the first way of code appears in those videos, so I thought maybe it was the version. What can I do to start using the few codes I know here, or how can I change it to be like to original.
I can imagine this question being so ambiguous it might have to many answeres. But the most simple one would enable me, I think, to continue, and understand it more deeply after.
Thanks!

Comment: yes on older versions I think the namespace was not given (there is an default one given in the project), there was no `partial` (which only means that you can define the `class` in multiple files and it's used here to hide the generated code (the `InitializeComponent` sub) into another file - in older versions this was placed into a `region` instead - don't bother with it - you can safely ignore all this for now and just place your controls and double-click to generate your handlers ;)

Comment: This is not Visual Basic, it is C#.  It looks entirely normal.  But sure, different from VB.  Pick the correct project template.

Comment: @Carsten Thank you very much. I'm finding dificulty doing it since, for example, when I doubleclick the controls, if I write Dim, it says it's a command not defined. But that might be an other problem. I'll try to solve it! Thans again :)

Answer (score 2):

You have created a new C# project, not a new VB project. Recreate the project from scratch and make sure when you are choosing a new project template that the category is Visual Basic.

[image]

Again, you MUST start over with a brand new project. You can't write VB in a C# project.